# Where is the Ftp option to publish Console Application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, console-application

I created a C# Console Application and now I want to publish it to a ftp server. However, when I got to the Publish screen, the only targets I see are, "Azure Webjobs" and "Folder".

Where is the other option that should read, "Ftp, IIs, etc"?

[screenshot of publish page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6NoX.png)

Comment: Only web projects allow publishing options like FTP and IIS. Console apps are not distributed in that way. What you see is often what you get.

Comment: Well, I hope they add it soon! Thanks anyway.

Comment: They won't add something that makes no sense. Even for web projects, nowadays they are rarely published via FTP.

Comment: Okay, Well that's a bummer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an option that allows FTP publish directly in visual studio for console applications. Although, as a workaround, you can publish to a folder and then upload that folder to your required FTP server through other third party FTP clients like Filezilla FTP client.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Ftp is supported for other applications but console?

Comment: Not all other application types. Personally, I have used FTP publish for web applications only. For console applications and class libraries, I have not seen any FTP options so far with versions upto Visual Studio 2017 Community version.

Comment: I have seen that option, and I publish apps to my server using FTP. I have no other, "simple way", to do it.

Comment: I'm totally not sure if such an option existed in older versions before visual studio community 2015 version, but it's just not there in current versions. Also these options do exist for web applications, websites, etc., so you might have used or seen these options on them. Also, you can't publish using FTP, but you can publish to a local folder and then use alternate FTP clients or scripts to send the published apps to FTP locations.

Comment: One more question. Any idea witch file I should run when I publish the app?

Comment: We don't need to run any file when we publish the app. When we publish, the project to be published along with all its dependencies build automatically by Visual Studio and upon success, the project is published to the set destination.